# pytest parametrize: How to pair specific inputs with corresponding expected outputs using fixtures?

Tags: unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-fixtures

I'm trying to use pytest's parametrize decorator to pair specific inputs with corresponding expected outputs and using fixtures for input values inside decorator. For example, I want to match the input **'56r 4j'** with the expected output **['56r 4j']** and **'5d 4s'** with **['5d 4s']**.
@pytest.fixture(params=['56r 4j', '5d  4s'])
def fixture_Sample1(request):
inputVal = np.array(request.param)
return inputVal

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[['56r 4j'], ['5d  4s']])
def fixture_Sample2(request):
    expectedVal = request.param
    return expectedVal


@pytest.mark.parametrize('input,expected_output', [
    (pytest_lazyfixture.lazy_fixture('fixture_Sample1'), pytest_lazyfixture.lazy_fixture('fixture_Sample2'))])
def test_val(input,expected_output):
    print('input is ' ,input)
    print('expected output ',expected_output)
```

However, I'm encountering an issue where each input is getting paired with each output, resulting in four cases instead of the intended two. The output can be seen in this snapshot: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BBLL.png

How can I modify my parametrize setup to achieve the desired pairing and get only two test cases?